# Atom missing text in main menu

Tags: 18.04, budgie, atom

I installed atom from official website as atom-amd64.deb on Ubuntu 18.04 Budgie Desktop 10.4. It is in version 1.34.0. When I start atom the menu items in the main menu are without text. I can click it and it works but either the text is not displayed or it has the same color as the background.

[image]

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 Budgie Desktop 10.4 in a VirtualBox and installed atom but there it worked. I know that there are many differences between this two systems.

[image]

What could be the problem? Where can I configure the colors or themes?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem and it was impossible to solve it for most of you because I didn't mention an important fact. My notebook is a Tuxedo. It comes with Ubuntu Budgie and a a Tuxedo Desktop Theme. The colors can be set in

```
System Tools -> Budgie Desktop Settings
```

The item

```
Widgets
```

is set to

```
Tuxedo-One-Darker
```

Now I can open atom and switch this option until I find a setting with good contrast.